# Compiling and Running Java Code in Sublime 3 (Mac)

Tags: java, macos, sublimetext3

I navigate to the Packages folder, BUT could only find an empty folder named user. Could someone tell me how to find and change system build file to run java code in sublime 3

Answer (score 0):

> Could someone tell me how to **find** <s>and change</s> system build file to run java code

---

`.sublime-package` files are located @:
`/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages/`
( *this is where most packages are located. IE: Package Control installations* )

unpackaged files and file overrides are located @:
`/Sublime Text 3/Packages/`

---

Both packaged & unpackaged files can be navigated and edited via [**PackageResourceViewer**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer)'s `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource` command.

Any files that are edited from a `.sublime-package` file will have a new instance created at `/Packages/PackageName/`.  The new file will now override the original file ( *which still exists in the* `.sublime-package` *file* ). The original file can be reactivated by deleting the override file.

Files that exist within `/Packages/` will be edited directly.

If both packaged & unpackaged instances of a file exist, `PackageResourceViewer` will open the unpackaged instance.

---

---

> Could someone tell me how to <s>find and</s> **change** system build file to run java code

---

- Open the command palette
- Run the `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource` command
- Navigate to `Java > JavaC.sublime-build`

---

The default `JavaC.sublime-build` will only compile Java, so you will need to create an alternative method which also runs the compiled code.

This can be done in several ways, including:

- [**external scripts**](https://gist.github.com/Enteleform/94dae9c3dce3a928ca96)
- [**build managers**](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/template-multi-command-builds-with-input-powershell-script/18683)
- [**plugins**](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/tips-on-making-a-buildsystem-plugin/1948/3)